# Add Horizontal panning to a stacked bar chart in Vega Spec

Tags: javascript, json, charts, visualization, vega

I am working on adding panning on a stacked bar chart to handle large volume of data and values are not cluttered on x-axis.

I tired couple of ways to do it, but could not.

I'm wondering if anyone could enable Panning on this Vega stacked barchart example:

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/stacked-bar-chart

JSON SPEC:

```
{



  `"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",`
  "description": "A basic stacked bar chart example.",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [


        {"x": 0, "y": 28, "c": 0}, {"x": 0, "y": 55, "c": 1},
        {"x": 1, "y": 43, "c": 0}, {"x": 1, "y": 91, "c": 1},
        {"x": 2, "y": 81, "c": 0}, {"x": 2, "y": 53, "c": 1},
        {"x": 3, "y": 19, "c": 0}, {"x": 3, "y": 87, "c": 1},
        {"x": 4, "y": 52, "c": 0}, {"x": 4, "y": 48, "c": 1},
        {"x": 5, "y": 24, "c": 0}, {"x": 5, "y": 49, "c": 1},
        {"x": 6, "y": 87, "c": 0}, {"x": 6, "y": 66, "c": 1},
        {"x": 7, "y": 17, "c": 0}, {"x": 7, "y": 27, "c": 1},
        {"x": 8, "y": 68, "c": 0}, {"x": 8, "y": 16, "c": 1},
        {"x": 9, "y": 49, "c": 0}, {"x": 9, "y": 15, "c": 1}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["x"],
          "sort": {"field": "c"},
          "field": "y"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "x"}
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true, "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "y1"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": "category",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "c"}
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "x", "zindex": 1},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "y", "zindex": 1}
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "x"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 1, "offset": -1},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y0"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "y1"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "c"}
        },
        "update": {
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    }
  ]


}
```

I tried using `type: "extent"` to get min and max value of timestamp data. and it kinda works but only symbol mark is moving, but rect mark is not moving while panning.

My data looks like this

```
data = [ { root: 123.33, grid: 223.44, sq: 422.66, total: 5440.9, starttimestamp: '2023-12-13T00:00:00' }]
```

I am transforming my starttimestamp value to

```
type : "formula", expr: "toDate(datum[\starttimestamp]\)", as : "timestamp"
```

and again transforming it with `type: "extent", field: "timestamp"`.